# How to get Mybatis Maven plugin to use a different java.library.path

Tags: java, maven, native, pom.xml, mybatis

I am currently using mybatis to generate java files.  The thing is that I need native libraries in order to access my database.  How would I handle this with the current plugin?

Here is what my pom looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>Generate MyBatis Artifacts</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>package.needs.native</groupId>
        <artifactId>needs-native</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: You can install those native libraries in local maven repository and configure them in pom.xml.